# Sci fi book - humans colonizing a planet, but it already had a human-like alien species

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

It was at my elementary school's Scholastic Book Fair, in 2017 or so, and was quite recently published at that time. The book is in English.

There are two main characters, a boy and a girl. The boy is human, the girl is an alien, but pretends to be human with a fake skin layer. Most boys at that time had replaced their hair with fake hair that was more malleable and more stylish, but the boy kept his natural hair.

There was a mysterious character with a watch, that allowed the user to travel through time. The main characters, at one point, had gotten access to the watch when the mysterious characater had lost it.

The girl's alien species had television-like devices, (i think tails as well), and were generally quite human. Humans were colonizing the girl's species' home planet, and the girl and her mother were tasked to stop the humans. Humans were pouring acid or something like that onto the home planet from robots orbiting in the atmosphere to destroy all native life.

They were on a space flight from Earth to the new planet, as part of the first (or first few) groups of humans going to the new planet. The two had both woken up during the spaceflight. They used a robot to collect resources to be turned into fuel for the aircraft. The boy finds out about this, and the girl tells the boy all about what the humans had done to her home planet.

I haven't found any similar or possible books that this could be so far.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Yep, I have, and added a bit more details.